# Deployin asp.net core 2.0 to Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku, heroku-cli

Made an app using asp.net and followed the instructions outlined in this [article](https://blog.devcenter.co/deploy-asp-net-core-2-0-apps-on-heroku-eea8efd918b6)
as I am using asp.net core 2.0. I got docker working and Heroku cli installed and got through all the steps but on the last one when I try and push to heroku I get the following in CMD

```
docker push registry.heroku.com/contentfulmvc/web
The push refers to repository [registry.heroku.com/contentfulmvc/web]
2c234e510117: Preparing
31dc395828e7: Preparing
6b64c53efec1: Preparing
293afe5e1723: Preparing
f18d175ee906: Preparing
7f6e826a29cb: Waiting
3aa2beece40f: Waiting
38072758390c: Waiting
684665cf5198: Waiting
4c71181bb594: Waiting
1245b259e2fa: Waiting
67903cf26ef4: Waiting
error parsing HTTP 400 response body: unexpected end of JSON input: ""
```

I don't know why its not working. Insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You get the above error when you have not created an app on heroku. You need to make sure that you have an app created and that you are referencing it when you push.